# Subtopics in Messaging Systems

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

Does ActiveMQ have suppport for subtopics? How do you define hierarchies of topics? Is there some naming convention to define the hierarchy relationships?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ActiveMQ supports subtopics in a virtual sense only, in that "subtopic-ness" is defined by naming convention, and subscriptions can use wildcards to view multiple topics.

As an example you might have a topic called `announcements`, to which you post messages. You then find that you want to divide between subjects of those announcements. In this case you would publish to different "subtopics" which are usually defined by convention using the "." character. Physically there is no subtopic created, just another topic with that name.

So you might now publish messages to `announcements.product` and `announcements.company`. If you want to consume from either of these, you subscribe as normal by name. If you want to consume all announcements, you would use [ActiveMQ's wildcard mechanism](http://activemq.apache.org/wildcards.html), and subscribe to `accouncements.>`